# How to use .pem file with Python M2Crypto

Tags: python, m2crypto, pem

To generate an RSA key pair I used openssl:

```
openssl genrsa -out my_key.private.pem 1024
openssl rsa -in my_key.private.pem -pubout -out my_key.public.pem
```

Now I want to use this my_key.public.pem file in a function of another .py file:

```
import M2Crypto
from M2Crypto import RSA,SSL

def encrypt():
    pk = open( 'my_key.public.pem', 'rb' ).read()
    rsa = M2Crypto.RSA.load_pub_key(pk)
    print rsa;
```

Am I doing it right?
Both files are in same directory, but this function is not giving any output.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [documentation](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/m2crypto/api/) the `load_pub_key` expects a file name as input. It returns a `M2Crypto.RSA.RSA_pub` object, which doesn't make sense to print. What exactly are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RSA.load_key('mykey.pem')
```