# File accessing in load_pub_key

Tags: python, m2crypto

Consider the following code:

```
fileHandle = open ( 'test8.pem','w' )
fileHandle.write (data)
pub_key = M2Crypto.RSA.load_pub_key(open('test8.pem'))
```

Which produces the following error:

```
 File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/M2Crypto/RSA.py", line 343, in load_pub_key
bio = BIO.openfile(file) 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/M2Crypto/BIO.py", line 186, in openfile
    return File(open(filename, mode))
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
```

How do I pass the file into `load_pub_key` method so it can be accessible by simply passing the file name?

Comment: exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176055/how-to-use-pem-file-with-python-m2crypto

Comment: your code doesn't correspond to your error. straighten your story.

Comment: no, it isn't. answer to that question quite clearly indicates that you need to pass filename to `load_pub_key`. if you want anything to be written to your file you'd need to flush the buffer by closing the `fileHandle`.

Comment: ya its duplicate but here the problem in accessing the file in the method.is there any other way to pass the file i.e with the directory?

Comment: problem is why the file is not opening after simply passing in the method

Comment: **answers to previous question clearly state that you must pass filename to `load_pub_key`**. is that clear now?

Answer (score 0):

If you pass test8.pem without quotes, Python interprets it as the name of a variable, which is not defined, hence the error.

I don't know the specific library you are using but I would guess that you need to pass fileHandle instead.

Answer (score 0):

this should work for you:

```
fname = 'test8.pem'
fileHandle = open(fname, 'w')
fileHandle.write(data)
fileHandle.close()
pub_key = M2Crypto.RSA.load_pub_key(fname)
```

Comment: thanks its seems cool but after applying this code again error :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RetEnc.py", line 17, in ?
    pub_key = M2Crypto.RSA.load_pub_key(fname)   
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/M2Crypto/RSA.py", line 344, in load_pub_key
    return load_pub_key_bio(bio)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/M2Crypto/RSA.py", line 360, in load_pub_key_bio
    rsa_error()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/M2Crypto/RSA.py", line 240, in rsa_error
    raise RSAError, m2.err_reason_error_string(m2.err_get_error())
M2Crypto.RSA.RSAError: no start line

Comment: so content of your file is malformed. and it's outside of the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same issue. I tried loading a file handler instead of path but it didn't help.

The thing that workout was using X509 module from M2Crypto. You can try use this functions to obtain a public key instance:

```
certificate = M2Crypto.X509.load_cert(cert_path)
pubkey = certificate.get_pubkey()
```

More details in the following answer:
[RSACryptoServiceProvider message signature verification with m2crypto](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8743213/2586315)