# Bad base64 Decode - M2Crypto - Python - Android - RSA

Tags: python, django, rsa, public-key-encryption, m2crypto

Trying to implement the signature verification of inapp billing on my server (Django/Python).

I found [this great](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544433/how-do-you-verify-an-rsa-sha1-signature-in-python) topic but I'm having issues with this line:

```
rsa = RSA.load_pub_key_bio(bio)
```

If I do it exactly as it is coded there I get a "RSAError: no start line" [and this makes sense since python didnt really like how pem was defined]

I decided to put my key into a .pem file and load it with

```
rsa = RSA.load_pub_key("public.pem")
```

However, I get a "RSAError: bad base64 decode" .  Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327211/file-accessing-in-load-pub-key

Comment: unfortunately no help there : /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, found and fixed my problem (but an explanation would be neat).

I had to have a \n every 75 chars ... formatting it like this made it work.

Comment: I looked up base64 and found that in some cases it has a maximum encoded line lenght